# How to Override the .ToString of a Property in a Class

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, tostring, overriding

I did search for this first and there are some similar posts, but i couldn't find my answer. :(

Lets say I have a Class:

```
Public Class ND
    Private mNumsDrawn = New List(Of Integer)

    Public Sub New(ByVal vNum As Integer)
        For i = 1 To vNum
            mNumsDrawn.Add(0)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Property NumsDrawn As List(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return mNumsDrawn
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Integer))
            mNumsDrawn = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I want to override the .ToString of the Property NumsDrawn.

If I put the .ToString override in the class then its just overriding the class' .ToString of course.  I could use this to output all the numbers in the list, but I want to change the output of one number in the draw.

```
Dim MyDraw = New ND(6)

MsgBox(MyDraw.ToString)
```

But what I want is something like this..

```
MsgBox(MyDraw.NumsDrawn(1).ToString)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with `MyDraw.NumsDrawn(1).ToString()` ?

Comment: You'll have to derive your own class from List(Of T).  That's possible.  Why you want to pass an argument to NumsDrawn is however very hard to guess.

Comment: I actually haven;t used Lists before and this was all set as arrays.  I'm passing an argument to Numsdrawn New because the size needs to be set and it can be different each time used, but then doesn't change.  I'll probably go back to arrays since I'm a little more familiar with them and the numbers don't change once set.  The Class ND is also just a subclass of a larger class, I tried to simplify the question.  y main question isn't even just .Tostring, its more how to create a Method for a Property in a class.  I'll work on the just creating another class way and see where it goes, thanks!

Comment: Alex, I wanted to override the NumsDrawn().ToString so I could Pad the integers with zeros.  But more General question is how to create a method of a property in a class (not proper wording probably).  Something like MyDraw.NumsDrawn(1).MyRoutine.  Anything I put in ND class will come out as Mydraw.MyRoutine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to have a custom `.ToString()` override on an Integer type ...but...

A simple way to do this would be to change your `NumsDrawn` from a `List(Of Integer)` to a `List(Of NumClass)` and then override the `.ToString` on *that* class:

```
Public Class ND
    Private mNumsDrawn As List(Of NumClass) = New List(Of NumClass)

    Public Sub New(ByVal vNum As Integer)
        For i = 1 To vNum
            mNumsDrawn.Add(New NumClass(0))
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Property NumsDrawn As List(Of NumClass)
        Get
            Return mNumsDrawn
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of NumClass))
            mNumsDrawn = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class NumClass
    Public Property Value As Integer
    Public Sub New(value As Integer)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "Here is my formatted value: " & Me.Value
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
    Dim myND As New ND(99)
    Debug.WriteLine(myND.NumsDrawn(6).ToString()) 'outputs:- Here is my formatted value: 0
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying that last night, but ran into some snags.  Will try later tonight.  I want to pad the string with zeros.  The problem I was having was when you tried to setNumsDrawn equal to an integer it would complain you can't set an integer to a NumClass (would be your example), but I was probably just doing somethign wrong.

Comment: Your code works perfectly.  I think I get where I was going wrong.  The New() for ND I was setting mNumsDrawn to 0, butif you set it to New NumClass then it overrides the ToString.  One question, when I do something like myND.NumsDrawn(1) = 1 it throws an exception because 1 is not of type NumClass.  I have to do myND.NumsDrawn(1) = (New NumClass(1)).  Is there a way to just use Integers still?

Comment: And its answer my problem in general with just having a "method of a property" in a class.  Any method I put in NumClass I can call by simply using myND.mNumsDrawn(1).myMethod().  But I really need a way to just store integers into the mNumsDrawn.

Comment: I hope you don't mind one more question.  Am I right in thinking that if I create a method for Numclass that changes Value it changes the value of myND.mNumsDrawn(?) that called the method?  Hope I;m making sense? :)

Comment: Doh, I was trying to do myND.NumsDrawn(1) = 1 when it should be myND.NumsDrawn(1).Value =1.  Thanks for your help, I think I figured most of it out through plugging away at your nicely working code.  Its good to just know that it can work so you keep going.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is overriding the `ToString()` method of `ND`. Although this is possible, it is IMO not really helpfull.

What will be more helpful is to define an extension method on `ND`. Notice that an extension method needs to be placed in a `Public Module` (which is effectively a static class).

This can be done as follows:

```
<Extension>
Public Function ToFormattedValue(instance As ND, index As Integer) As String
    Return instance.NumsDrawn(index).ToString()
End Function

' Use as:
MessageBox.Show(MyDraw.ToFormattedValue(1))
```

If you still want to *override* the `ToString` method, the code is almost the same. It is not really overriding it just adding an overload. Like this:

```
Public Class ND
    ' Other code here
    Public Function ToString(index as Integer) As String
        Return Me.NumsDrawn(1).ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at Extension last night as well, but didn't go for with it.  I think the problem with both is the code to access the to string is on the class again.  It will work, but doesn't seem quite intuitive.  I'd really like to access the property's tostring as MyDraw.NumsDrawn(1).ToString if possible.  I sort of got it working last night by creating another class for Number, but then two problems arise.  I can't use integer's for NumsDrawn anymore very easily and when I try and do a New routine to initialise NumsDrawn Its throwing an exception in the form now.

Comment: I'll look up extension, but your example looks like the same outcome as just creating a method for the ND class?